# BeautifulSoup Error Message?

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup

My first time using BeautifulSoup. I watched a youtube video and mimicked what they did. I'm trying to pull rent prices from an apt website, but I keep getting this meesage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\rent.py", line 5, in <module>
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.equityapartments.com/washington-dc/georgetown/2400-m-apartments##unit-availability-tile").read()
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Eun Hae Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

What is the cause of this error message?

The Code I used was

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.equityapartments.com/washington-dc/georgetown/2400-m-apartments##unit-availability-tile").read()
soup = bs.beautifulsoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup - you are getting a 400 from your `urlopen` action, from the remote server.  You need to review your URL and determine why it is not a legal `GET`.

Comment: from what i've been reading, it sounds like the way around this is by adding a user agent?

Comment: @user134365: It certainly could be - you need to look at a known-successful request and then determine what is different between that request and your request here.  You should also review the Terms of Use of the website in question in order to not be violating them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.equityapartments.com/washington-dc/georgetown/2400-m-apartments##unit-availability-tile"
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print (soup)
```

Comment: I get another error message: ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: have python version are you using?

Comment: i'm using python 3.5.1

Comment: you can install it if you'd like on the command line type:pip3 install requests